# Slight change in what I am drawing using tikz and node

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hi All: I am using tikz (I'm a total newbie )  and was drawing this and it worked.

```
% labels

    \foreach \y/\m/\mm in {2.5/00/05}
        \draw (-2, \y) node{11:\m\,-\,11:\mm};
```

But now I just want to change it slightly so that it's a subscript in math mode.

```
%labels

    \foreach \y/\m/\mm in {2.5/00/05}
        \draw (-2, \y) node{DERZZZ$_{(11:\m\,-\,11:\mm)$};
```

That gives the following:

```
Runaway argument?
\draw (-2, \y ) node{DERZZZ$_{(11:\m \,-\,11:\mm )$}; 
! Paragraph ended before \pgffor@next was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.35 
     
?
```

Maybe I'm not supposed to use node when doing this ? In fact, it's never clear
to me when to use node and when to just use latex ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're forgetting braces after `\foreach ... in{}`: `\foreach \y/\m/\mm in {2.5/00/05}
   { \draw (-2, \y) node {DERZZZ$_{(11:\m\,-\,11:\mm)}$}; } ` works for me.

Comment: @jairoADelRio: Thanks. That did work. But I didn't need them in the other one where I didn't use math mode. Is that some kind of rule of tikz ? Thanks again.

Comment: @JairoDelRio: Just one more bother about this. I then take the pdf created by that code and insert as a file into a beamer document. When I do that, the size is INCREDIBLY TINY compared to the one where I didn't use math mode. Is there a way to keep it the same size as before. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look carefully: you have into your node:

[image]

1. open node
2. start math mode
3. start subscript
4. stop math mode **without stopping subscript**

(an editor with syntax highlight helps here, as you see).

So LaTeX is right, you have a runaway argument.

This:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \foreach \y/\m/\mm in {2.5/00/05}
        \draw (0, \y) node{11:\m\,-\,11:\mm}; 
        
        \foreach \y/\m/\mm in {2.5/00/05}
        \draw (4, \y) node{DERZZZ$_{(11:\m\,-\,11:\mm)}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

Notice a couple of things more: on the left, you have a dash (-) in text mode, and on the right you have a minus in math mode (between the hours). Are you sure you want this and not, for example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \foreach \y/\m/\mm in {2.5/00/05}
       \draw (0, \y) node{11:\m{} -- 11:\mm};

        \foreach \y/\m/\mm in {2.5/00/05}
        \draw (4, \y) node{DERZZZ\textsubscript{(11:\m{} -- 11:\mm)}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

where using the correct mode (it's text, not math!) and the correct character (en-dash) avoid the need to use manual spacing?

[image]

As for your question, in a `tikzpicture`, all text must go into a structure --- for example, a node.

And why you export your `tikzpicture` as PDF to put in `beamer`? Just use the code...

Comment: that was AMAZINGLY helpful. Thanks Rmano. and, in general. thanks to everyone on this stack. exchange. It's really incredible and filled with insanely knowledgeable people.